# What is meant by static monolithic build when building tensorflow from source?

Tags: tensorflow

While installing tensorflow from source there is an option to configure the build with this command.

```
--config=monolithic —Configuration for a mostly static, monolithic build.
```

What is meant by static monolithic build and how does it affect my tensorflow build if i use it / don't use it.?

Answer (score 5):

AFAIK it basically disables the support for adding your own operations to TensorFlow, (like described in https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/extend/op) by removing the dependency to `libtensorflow_framework.so`. So if you don't want to add your own operations, `--config=monolithic` is probably what you want.

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/ad27775640e0d9c506247e91a2306c63703c97d0/.bazelrc#L16

Comment: if I just want to use tensorflow c++ api for inference, does this means that I can build tensorflow with this flag without any problem? or it is depend on `.pb` file?

Comment: @SaeedMasoomi Depends. If you have to compile additional modules like tensorflow-addons for which no existing python wheels exit, then the installation will fail, because tensorflow-addons is searching for the shared object (so) file.